# Column width in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column

I would like to customize the width ( make them narrow, with 2 lines of headline ) of the columns in my SharePoint library. As far as I searched it can be done in SharePoint Designer with codes. Yet, I am wondering if there is any easy way to do that since I am not a SPD expert.

I would appreciate if you could help me on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What constitutes an "easy" way? That is a very personal point. If you are looking for a browser solution, then maybe JavaScript could be used, but I don't know if that is "easier" than using SharePoint Designer. So instead of a subjective "easy" please specify what you would like to use if it's not SPD.

Comment: @peter you have right about the implication of 'easy' since its meaning varies from one to another. So, to make my question more objective, I would rephrase it: Is there a way to customize the width of the columns without writing any code in SPD? If there is no way to do that, could you tell me the code that I can insert in SPD to customize it?

Comment: You can open the page with the list view in SharePoint Designer and set the width without code. In Design View you can select the column and use the ribbon tools to set the column width in pixels. No code.

Comment: @teylyn thank you for the help! It worked. So, i would like to elaborate your answer for beginners like me: In SharePoint Designer 2007, after opening the site that you'd like work on, Task Panes> Navigation> Double Click on the library you would like to work on. Then, you will be able to customize the width and also the headline for the colum. ( In case of you want to write the headline in two rows )